# VB.net in visual studio-how to retrieve specific data from database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlcommand

I am using visual studio to create a window base system by using VB.net and the database is wizard inside the visual studio. How to retrieve specific data set and show in textbox? For example, i have 
 userid, username and address inside my database. I would like to show the username and address when key in the userid.

Comment: its better to try some tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I understood that the UserId will be an input (lets say: Text1.text).

1.You will need to connect to your database.

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
Conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
Conn.Open()
```

2.Pass your query. Consider validation on your UserId if need be

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = Conn
cmd.CommandText = "Select username,address from YourTable where Userid = '" & Text1.Text & "'"
```

3.Execute the query on db

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
dr = cm.ExecuteReader
```

4.Display your data on screen and close objects used

```
If dr.HasRows Then

dr.Read()
username.text = dr.Item("username")
address.text = dr.Item("address")

dr.Close()

EndIf
Conn.Close()
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Well kudos for the tutorial, but please, do not teach how to leave an Sql Injection vulnerability

Comment: additional question. how If i wan to navigate to next record?

Comment: check this [LINK](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/246662/data-base-move-previous-next-first-and-last)